# Encoding issue with System.out in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, printstream

I'm having difficulties with my logger that I embedded into a `JTextArea`: when I call the `logger.append()` method, it just works fine, but when I use `System.out.println()`, all my French accents are lost.

Here, you have the creation of the logger and the redirection of `System.out` and `System.err` to it.

```
this.logger = new TextAreaOutputStream(jta, jsp.getVerticalScrollBar());
System.setProperty("user.langage", "fr");
PrintStream ps;
ps = new PrintStream(this.logger, true, "UTF-8");
System.setOut(ps);
System.setErr(ps);
```

Here, you have the `TextAreaOutputStream` class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    private JTextArea jta;
    private JScrollBar jsb;

    public TextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea jta, JScrollBar jsb) {
        this.jta = jta;
        this.jsb = jsb;
    }

    public synchronized void append(String s) {
        this.jta.append(s);
        scroll();
    }

    public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
        jta.append(String.valueOf((char) b));
        if (((char) b) == '\n')
            scroll();
    }

    private synchronized void scroll() {
        if ((jsb.getValue() + jsb.getVisibleAmount()) == jsb.getMaximum()) 
            jta.setCaretPosition(jta.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

I tried to change the encoding of the `PrintStream` to random encodings, it changed the look of the misprinted accents, but I never could have it right. I also tried to change the accents with unicode entries such as `\u00e9` for `é`, but it did not change anything.

Here, I'm desperate enough to ask for your help,

Romain

Comment: Are you sure about "user.langage"? Isn't it "user.language" (note the 'u')?

Comment: You should check what encoding are you using in your development tool. If you use Eclipse click left on the Project -> Properties -> Resource (and check you are using UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: @fge It's clearly wrong, but then again, it has probably nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: maqjav > I checked the place you mentioned but `UTF-8` was already my default-inherited encoding. The encoding error must come from another issue. @fge and @Marko > you're both right. It's wrong but irrelevant to the bug. Got it corrected anyway, so thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `OutputStream` is wrong: you pretend that `write(int)` receives characters, but in fact it receives raw bytes. If you check out `PrintStream`, you'll see that its `print` and `append` methods first apply encoding and then eventually call `write(int)` for each encoded byte.

You shoud not attempt to transfer raw bytes back to the string in your `TextArea`. Instead implement `PrintStream` and its character-based methods and shove those strings/char arrays directly into the UI component.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your advice. My TextAreaOutputStream implementation has been inspired by many implementation examples of such a class I found on the web (including SO). Those are all `TextArea` extending an `OutputStream`. Also the `print` methods of `PrintOutput` are all 1-liners using `String.valueOf()` methods in the same way I do.

Comment: I can only say that those examples are ugly hacks, and you are the one who exposes them as such: they work only for ASCII or other single-byte encondings.